# PGP/GnuPG to encrypt

Tags: python, gnupg

Need to use PGP/GnuPG to encrypt.can suggest what the Python packages to use that.
for PGP encryption i.e. on the other side is PGP used to decrypt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [python-gnupg](http://code.google.com/p/python-gnupg/). Encryption is covered in the docs [here](http://www.red-dove.com/python_gnupg/index.html#encryption-and-decryption).